# Google Calendar Events Change MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'll be straightforward and ask what exactly I'm trying to do and if anyone could help me out that would be great to know whether what I'm trying to do is possible or not. I am using the Yii framework with a MySQL database in the back. I want to integrate multiple different user's calender's in a Google calendar. Also, I would like to know if it's possible, either with the Google Calendar API, using Yii, or the gData library in Zend (If I can even do that since I'm already using the Yii framework) to have changes made to the calender performs changes to the MySQL database.

For example, if a user changes his calendar of an appointment from two hours to one hour, that change needs to reflect in the database where appointment lengths are stored.

I essentially want to be able to make changes to the database every time an appointment/event is added, deleted, or edited.

Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the extension [EgCal](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/egcal/) for this problem before.

Comment: Would I just program it in Yii that upon a successful return after an event creation, modification, or deletion to make the changes in mysql then? Thank you for your patience and I really appreciate your help.